# Can't write CSV in Exiftool when called from C# (output goes to screen)

Tags: c#, exiftool

I have a c# process that uses exiftool to scan the contents of a directory and dump it into a csv file. While in 'real' code the aim will be that any output gets picked up by c#, for debugging I am explicitly starting a visible process so I can debug. In reality it has no relevance for the problem, regardless of the process window it's the same.

```
Process prc_exifTool = new Process();

prc_exifTool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

prc_exifTool.StartInfo.FileName = "exiftool.exe";
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
//tmpCSVFileName is a csv file whose name is the same as the folder that's being scanned + ".csv" 
File.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), tmpCSVFileName)).Dispose(); // seems to be needed else the output complains that the file does not exist

prc_exifTool.Start();
prc_exifTool.WaitForExit();
```

...where

```
args =  -k -a -g -s -charset filename=utf8 -charset exif=utf8 -charset iptc=utf8 -ee -struct -progress -c "%.6f" -GPSAltitude -exif:GPSAltitude -ext jpg -csv -Directory "D:\temp" > "C:\Users\nemet\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.csv"
```

(in reality there's a fair few more tags and file formats and I won't ultimately be requiring to wait for ENTER to be pressed but for debug & the sake of keeping this comparatively short here, I'm not listing them as they're not relevant)

**problem:**

When I use a cmd window and type in manually `"exiftool -k -a -g .... (args)"`  [obvs substitute with args] the process runs okay and the csv gets filled with relevant data.
When I run the c# code the output instead of going into a csv file all goes onto the screen.
What am I doing incorrectly? One thing I've noticed that if I do cmd then the message is that "1 directories scanned", which is correct but when done in c# the msg says "2 directories scanned", so I think it's thinking the CSV is a folder, not a file.

This link https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7835.0 brings up a similar issue but there they're using OSX whereas I'm using Windows and the author doesn't really provide an answer apart from *...And I don't know if redirection (">") will work in the GUI.* -- and suggests reading the FAQ, which doesn't really mention much on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging....the ">" is a redirect function of CMD, which doesn't really exist in that particular context that was in my question and so it does not work.
Instead CMD itself must be launched as a process.
The following logic works: [doubleQuote is just that, " <-- introduced as a string further up in the code]

```
Process prc_exifTool = new Process();
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k " + doubleQuote + "exiftool " + args  + doubleQuote + "&& exit"; // the "&& exit" is needed otherwise the cmd.exe never exits.
```

This creates the CSV file as required while maintaining the ability to parse the output for further processing.

Should anyone be interested, to parse the output "live" the whole code:

```
Process prc_exifTool = new Process();
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k " + doubleQuote + "exiftool " + args  + doubleQuote + "&& exit";

prc_exifTool.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

prc_exifTool.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
prc_exifTool.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

prc_exifTool.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
});
prc_exifTool.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
});

prc_exifTool.Start();
prc_exifTool.BeginOutputReadLine();
prc_exifTool.BeginErrorReadLine();
prc_exifTool.WaitForExit();
prc_exifTool.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the write up.  This has popped up a few times with regards to exiftool and you've given me something to point to in the future.